# Error when custom data is added to Azure OpenAI Service Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-storage-account, azure-openai

I receive the following error when adding my custom data which is a .txt file (it doesn't matter whether I add it via Azure Cognitive Search, Azure Blob Storage, or File Upload or whether the respective Congnitive Search index contains any data):

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqFr.png)

The error as text:
Error
Server disconnected
LLM call failed for chat completion endpoint. Please set OAIGenerationConfig(is_chat=True)

After removing the Data Source, everything works fine again and the bot responds to my queries.

I am using an Azure OpenAI Service with a gpt-35-turbo deployment, which has the following details:
Version: 0301, Deployment Type: Standard, Capacity: 120K TPM

I have no idea at the moment how I should further approach this problem.

Any advice is much appreciated!

**Edit:** I had the OpenAI resource deployed to West Europe and redeployed it to East US. It now works perfectly as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question that any code or error details in the text format not in the image?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean - the error I get is posted in-chat and there is no more information provided by Azure than what I put in my Question as both image and text.

Comment: can you test the same in another region? It may hint on a possible issue in the original geography.

Comment: I had the OpenAI resource deployed to West Europe and redeployed it to East US. It now works - Azure never fails to amaze me, thank you for your suggestion (: Can I Somehow mark your comment as an answer for the question or should I write an answer myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you test the same in another region? It may hint on a possible issue in the original geography.

Comment: The obligatory comment here so that people can see it: I had the OpenAI resource deployed to West Europe and redeployed it to East US. It now works - Azure never fails to amaze me, thank you for your suggestion (: